# ¿alguien sabe como puedo poner una fecha como nombre de una columna en phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

resulta que tengo un php con datos y uno de estos es una fecha y lo quiero poner como nombre de una columna pero me saca un error, saben como puedo hacerle para que no me salga ese error, este es el php

```
<?php
require('../../conexion.php');

$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$asistencia=$_POST['asistencia'];

$sql="ALTER TABLE asistencias ADD $fecha varchar(15) NOT NULL";
$result=$conexion->query($sql);

if($result)
{
    $sql2="UPDATE asistencias "
        . "SET "
        . "$fecha='$asistencia' "
        . "WHERE Id=$id";
    $result2=$conexion->query($sql2);
    if($result2)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'error';
        echo $sql2;
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'error';
    echo $sql;
}
?>
```

Comment: Pero... ¿cómo le vas a poner a una columna como nombre una fecha? O sea, ¿quieres que una columna de tu tabla se llame 18 de abril de 2017? ¿qué utilidad tendría eso? Un buen nombre para una columna sería `fecha_venta`, `fecha_nacimiento`, `fecha_otracosa` y en los valores sí, introduces algo como `20170418`. Lee esto: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: es que estoy haciendo un control de asistencia y quiero generar un campo para cada fecha y este se llene con las palabras "asistió" o "inasistio" dependiendo del id del empleado

Comment: Piensa tu tabla en **vertical**, no en **horizontal**. Crear una columna por cada asistencia es una locura. Puedes tener una tabla con dos o tres columnas: `id_empleado, fecha, estatus_asistencia` y en cada fila de la tabla registras los datos de cada empleado. Luego relacionas esa tabla con la tabla empleados por el `id_empleado`. Puedes tener **hacia abajo** millones de filas de todos los empleados que quieras, con todas las fechas que quieras. En cambio, si por cada asistencia creas una columna con el nombre de la fecha... uffff. Las bases de datos no funcionan como estás pensando.

Comment: @A.Cedano te está dando la clave del asunto. No se trata de aumentar el número de columnas, que puede volver el sistema ingestionable. En su lugar, una tabla relacionada con el id del empleado que almacene fecha de asistencia. No tener una fecha en concreto puede significar no asistir.  Reduces así el número de registros.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes revisar la documentación al respecto [Nombres de bases de datos, tablas, índices, columnas y alias](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.0/es/legal-names.html).

Para nombres de columnas en concreto puedes utilizar cualquier carácter con un límite de 64 caracteres del conjunto de caracteres actual.

El diseñador es libre de establecer los nombres que crea oportunos para las columnas, aún que mi recomendación es seguir unas reglas mínimas:

- Utilizar caracteres alfanuméricos, sin caracteres estraños como la ñ, tildes o silimales.
- Limitar los nombres a menos de 32 caracteres.
- Utilizar el guión bajo ( _ ) para separar palabras.
- Utilizar siempre palabras en minúsculas, algunos motores te lo convierten automáticamente.
- Los nombres de las tablas deberían ir en plural y los nombres de las columnas en singular.
- En una tabla, colocar primero la clave primaria seguida de las claves foráneas.

Tu sentencia no funciona por que debes entrecomillar el nombre de la tabla ya que puede contener espacios u otros caracteres que hacen que la la consulta no sea válida.

Así debería funcionar:

```
$sql="ALTER TABLE asistencias ADD '$fecha' varchar(15) NOT NULL";
```

No obstante, no puedo recomendarte que sigas por este camino, como bien te han comentado lo que quieres hacer es un error de concepto. No sólo por qué tu tabla crecerá a lo ancho (poco recomendable), piensa en lo complejo que se puede volver hacer consultas a esa tabla.

Por otro lado, elijas la opción que elijas deberías prevenir mínimamente la [inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: o weno, esta bien, gracias n.n